# What is the purpose of bindaddress in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

In [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#bindaddress) we can read:
"The IP of the outgoing IP address to use for the performing the request."

That is not clear for me. Anyone can explain with more details what is the purpose of `bindaddress` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computer where Scrapy is running might have multiple network connections, each with their own unique IP network address (or addresses, plural).  For example, a laptop might have a WiFi connection and a wired Ethernet connection.  A larger server-class system might have several Ethernet connections.  Even a system that has a single network connection might have multiple IP addresses, some for IPv4 and others for IPv6.

The `bindaddress` option can be used to tell Scrapy which one of those local IP addresses should be used as the source address on its outgoing requests.

If you don't specify which local address you want Scrapy to use, then Scrapy will let the system choose the address.  That choice is usually the local address that the system thinks is "closest" to the destination address of the request.  This would be the usual situation.  Unless you have a particular need to use a specific source address, there's no reason to use the `bindaddress` option.